# Site not working header

Tags: asp.net

Sorry for my English. I editing site in asp and I have a problem, the header is not visible http://edusf.ru/project/default1.aspx

But the normal version, with a working header http://edusf.ru/project/

I can not understand the problem. Here is the code page default1.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Bitrix.UI.BXPublicPage, Main"  Title="Демо страница" %>
<script runat="server" id="@__bx_pagekeywords">
    public override void SetPageKeywords(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> keywords)
    {
        keywords[@"keywords"]=@"";
        keywords[@"description"]=@"";
        keywords[@"ShowLeftColumn"]=@"";
    }
</script>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="bxcontent" runat="server" >
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
                    $("#about-button").css({
                opacity: 0.3
            });
            $("#contact-button").css({
                opacity: 0.3
            });
                    $("#page-wrap div.button").click(function(){
                                $clicked = $(this);
                                        if ($clicked.css("opacity") != "1" && $clicked.is(":not(animated)")) {
                                        $clicked.animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        borderWidth: 5
                    }, 600 );
                    var idToLoad = $clicked.attr("id").split('-');
                    $("#content").find("div:visible").fadeOut("fast", function(){
                        $(this).parent().find("#"+idToLoad[0]).fadeIn();
                    })
                }
                $clicked.siblings(".button").animate({
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }, 600 );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

<div id="home-button" class="button">

<img src="button-1.png" alt="home" class="button" />

</div>

<img style="float: left;" src="devide.png" width="2" height="24" />

<div id="about-button" class="button">

<img src="button-2.png" alt="about" class="button">

</div>
<img style="float: left;" src="devide.png" width="2" height="24" />
<div id="contact-button" class="button">

<img src="button-3.png" alt="contact" class="button">

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div id="content">

<div id="home">

<p><h1>Социальный образовательный портал</h1>
<table class="st2"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td class="left" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p>Социальный образовательный портал &ndash; это веб-сервис для обучения через общение всех участников учебного процесса. Как и в любой системе обучения в данном сервисе есть возможность изучения курсов и прохождения тестов. Но главный принцип работы пользователей в сервисе &ndash; общение, интерактивное взаимодействие в решении задач и создание личного виртуального пространства.</p>
       </td><td class="right" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p>Участвуя в жизни портала, каждый пользователь сервиса становится частью информационного пространства учебного заведения или организации. Если в привычном понимании портал - это обширная и систематизированная база учебных материалов и документов, то социальный образовательный портал - это актуальные знания каждого из его участников в динамике.</p>
       </td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

<table class="st2"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td class="left" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p><img height="236" width="370" src="/project/src001.jpg" alt="Социальный образовательный портал" /></p>
       </td><td class="right" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p><img height="236" width="370" src="/project/src002.jpg" alt="Социальный образовательный портал" /></p>
       </td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

<table class="st3"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td class="left" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p>В отличие от традиционных систем дистанционного обучения (СДО), данный сервис усиливает направляющую роль преподавателя. Активность обучаемых видна преподавателям, что способствует их профессиональной ориентации, раскрытию творческого потенциала и вовлечению в общественную жизнь. </p>
       </td><td class="middle" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p>Обучаемые также могут наблюдать активность друг друга, что делает процесс обучения прозрачным, мотивирует к соперничеству и достижению лучших результатов в учебной и не учебной деятельности.</p>
       </td><td class="right" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p>В СДО под самостоятельной работой обучаемых фактически подразумевается его изоляция от друзей и от более качественных и актуальных учебных материалов, а Социальный образовательный портал предлагает коллективную работу по выработке и накоплению знаний, где самостоятельность означает лидерство. </p>
       </td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>

<p style="text-align: center;"><img height="251" width="810" src="/project/diag001.jpg" alt="Социальный образовательный портал" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;" /></p>

<table class="st2"> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr><td class="left" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p>В Социальном образовательном портале используются средства неформального общения, знакомые пользователям по популярным социальным сервисам. Это помогает пользователям более активно взаимодействовать друг с другом: делиться полезной информацией, интенсивно использовать навыки общения, коллективно решать задачи, и выполнять групповые учебные и творческие проекты.</p>

        <p>Используя социальный образовательный портал, Вы получаете управление интеллектуальным капиталом Вашей организации и творческим потенциалом Ваших студентов и работников. В процессе взаимодействия пользователей генерируются уникальные новые решения и информационные ресурсы. Вы можете применять их для последующего цикла обучения и в целях совершенствования бизнес-процессов Вашей организации.</p>
       </td><td class="right" style="-moz-border-top-colors: none; -moz-border-right-colors: none; -moz-border-bottom-colors: none; -moz-border-left-colors: none; -moz-border-image: none;"> 
        <p><strong>Социальный образовательный портал включает в себя взаимодополняющий функционал продуктов трёх типов:</strong></p>

        <ul> 
          <li>система управления сайтом (администрирование, управление правами пользователей, учебные группы, настройка интерфейса, обновление учебного контента, добавление общих компонент: новости, объявления, галереи); </li>

          <li>система дистанционного обучения (курсы и тесты в формате SCORM, статистика обучения, вебинары, календари событий, управление проектным обучением); </li>

          <li>социальная сеть (блоги, группы друзей, фотоальбомы, комментарии, хранение документов, события, закладки и обмен ими). 
            <br />
           Все пользователи сервиса имеют одинаковый набор инструментов, отличающийся только возможностями, зависящими от роли (студент, преподаватель, куратор и др.) </li>
         </ul>
       </td></tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
</p>

</div>

<div id="about">

<p>Cтраница находится в разработке</p>

</div>

<div id="contact">

<p>Cтраница находится в разработке</p>

</div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your non-working example, the header image from styles.css which is looking at: http://edusf.ru/project/images/head.jpg which is throwing a 404, not found. It is overriding the setting from  template_styles.css

In your working example is getitng it from template_styles.css, and getting the following working image http://edusf.ru/bitrix/templates/edusf/images/head.jpg